# SSRS Numeric fields appear as #Error yet they return data when query run in Query Designer and SSMS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

My SSRS Report from SQL 2019 works except for 3 Numeric Fields that display as #Error. They are defined as (money, not null). The query runs in Query Manager and SSMS and returns expected values. They are all using an expression like this

```
=First(Fields!Balance, "DataSet1")
=First(Fields!Amount, "DataSet1")
=First(Fields!Total, "DataSet1")
```

All 3 fields are in the dataset indicated and the case matches. I've saved the report and refreshed the fields in the dataset. Text and integer values from the same Tables as these columns are displaying fine. I can't figure out why the dataset query will run fine but the Preview shows #Error.
I went through a number of google suggestions (Changed textbox number property to default from currency, refreshed in preview screen, remove the ***.rdl.data file) but am getting nowhere. Any direction would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the `Value` property, at the moment you are returning the field object.

Change it to

```
=First(Fields!Balance.Value, "DataSet1")
```

and it should work.